# Is there a valid close reason for too basic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just came across a decently written question, that basically shows a method `foo()` that takes a list of string as input, and returns a single string.

The OP wanted to know why it gives an error when you go `listOfStringsVar = foo()`.

Within 5 minutes, there are like 6 answers all going "the method returns a single string, not list of strings which is expected by `listOfStringsVar`".

Now, I feel like close-voting this question. I am just wondering: would that be correct, and if so, with what reason?

Comment: The description of the typographical error fits this really well _"While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."_ But the first sentence wouldn't fly.

Comment: @George I know. That is why I didn't use that one. Or any other.

Comment: Even if question is basic, it still is clear and could help others, but probably best suited reason to close would be "close as duplicate of question which solves *similar* problem". My only problem with it that people instead of up-voting correct answer try to provide yet another one which doesn't add anything new...

Comment: "_probably best suited reason to close would be "close as duplicate of question which solves similar problem_" hoping that the duplicate is well explained. A trivial problem generally means a newbie so the duplicate could not be understood. But I agree, this is the best way for "too basic" question. If the question is well asked (and in topic), even simple question deserve an answer (if none could be found already)

Comment: Well, there is no close-reason for 'duplicate of every Computer 101 course, every beginner textbook and and every newbie tutorial site'.  I usually go with too broad, unclear.or off-topic 'asking for tutorial'.

Comment: @MartinJames None of that fits. That is the whole point.

Comment: @GhostCat oh - I know that.  I have to go with what is available.  SO will not add a close-reason of 'OP is incompetent ATM and cannot program computers at even a basic level without continual hand-holding'.